# How to call Assembly Functions from C on x86 architecture?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86

Unfortunately, the internet is lacking a guide on how to implement the x86 Assembly into C programs. Also, noobies are wondering about the different syntaxes (IT&T and Intel).

Personally, I am not sure how to exactly do this, handling the different compilers/assemblers like NASM or GCC.

I have created the following, highly sophisticated program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add_imm(int,int);

int main(int argv, char** argc){
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;
  int c = add_imm(a,b);
  printf("%d", c);
}
```

Together with this other highly sophisticated program:

```
SECTION .TEXT
      GLOBAL add_imm

add_imm:
    push rbp
    mov rsp, rbp
    mov rax, [rbp+24]
    mov rbx, [rbp+16]
    add rax, rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Compiling that with:

```
nasm -f elf64 add_imm.S
gcc main.c add_imm.o -o tes
```

Throws a compiler error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add_imm", referenced from:
      _main in main-019ea6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

So I thought it would be worthwhile if someone could create an explanation of how to really embed assembly language into C. 
What is important to consider? What are the general calling conventions?

Note: I am using macOS, but I hope it will work on Linux as well.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Note that the calling convention is most likely wrong, too.  But I can't say for sure without knowing what operating system you are programming for.

Comment: @fuz: I don't think GCC has been ported to any x86-64 OS where the standard calling convention is stack args.  AFAIK the only 3 supported conventions are x86-64 SysV and Windows x64 fastcall and vectorcall (same but with `__m128` passed in XMM regs instead of by reference).

Comment: @PeterCordes I really don't like making assumptions as doing so came back to bite me again and again.  It is OP's duty to provide sufficient information and until he provides enough details to give an unambiguous answer, I'm not going to answer the question.

Comment: @fuz: sure, me neither, just saying that we can basically rule out the asm being correct :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed.  Isn't that exactly what I wrote in my original comment?  Btw, Go uses a stack-only calling convention on amd64, so there's that.

Comment: @fuz: you said "most likely" wrong.  I'm saying "certainly wrong" or at least was trying to leave less room for doubt than your phrasing without making a 100% absolute claim (because yeah, being bitten by over-confident assumptions has happened to me, too).  But in this case I have a reason for believing it's impossible.  Good point about Go, though; this may be intended to be called from Go.  Also, I thought the leading underscore in 64-bit mode GCC is looking for would imply MacOS (not Linux or Windows), but this is using `-felf64` not `macho64`, so it might be something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's probably macOS and OP has cobbled his example together from multiple tutorials for i386 (hence the calling convention) and amd64 Linux (hence the nasm invocation and lack of leading underscore).  However, without input from OP, I cannot say.

Comment: @fuz: Agreed, but I was thinking that MacOS GCC (which is actually clang) would complain if you fed it an ELF object file, before it got to the point of looking for symbols in it.  Maybe not, or maybe the build commands were copy-pasted from a tutorial instead of being the ones the OP actually ran, or IDK what.

Comment: Apart from calling convention, in MASM I would make the function availble with `PUBLIC add_imm`.

Comment: @PeterCordes gcc doesn't check the object file, the linker is what does that.  And if it's the GNU linker (which is weird for macOS) it uses the libbfd and thus doesn't really care about object file formats as long as the architectures match.

Comment: @WeatherVane: This is NASM; `GLOBAL add_imm` does that.

Comment: Yes, I am using macOS and the code has been copied from various tutorials. Thanks for your clarification in the comments. These are (I am using) the calling conventions I learned in university.

Comment: In addition gcc for macOs is indeed clang

Comment: @Niclas Cool!  Now I can write an answer.  Make sure to always specify this in your question!  Would have saved me a lot of time waiting for a response from you.

Comment: MacOS *is* a Unix.  Moreso than Linux, you could argue, since it traces its heritage back to FreeBSD.  Linux is a re-implementation of Unix and is POSIX-compliant, but some people don't like to call it Unix.  Or did you mean a Unix like x86-64 Solaris or original FreeBSD, OpenBSD or NetBSD?

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right.
Thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing you need to do to write a function in assembly is to follow the ABI (application binary interface) of the platform you are programming for.  This document specifies:

- what the width of types in the C language (`int`, `long`, `float`, ...) and standard library are
- how structures are laid out in memory
- how functions are called (function call sequence), specifically

  - how arguments are passed to functions
  - what registers need to be preserved by functions
  - how the return value is returned to the caller
  - how to actually call the function
- how C identifiers are translated (decorated/mangled) into symbols
- how to access static and thread-local variables and functions
- what memory model is used

The ABI is different for each operating system and architecture and you should not make assumptions about it.  Most importantly, code examples for one operating system and architecture will most likely not work on another, even if they have the same operating system or architecture.  x86_64-linux is a different platform than x86_64-osx!

For x86_64-osx, the relevant ABI document is the [OS X ABI Function Call Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI) which refers to the [x86_64 SysV ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf).  The main difference is in how identifiers are decorated (with a leading underscore) and some details about shared objects which don't necessarily need to concern you right now.

For particularly pesky details, it is usually a good idea to write some C code and then ask the compiler to generate assembly code with the `-S` option.  To do the same thing in assembly, just do whatever the compiler does.

Having gotten that out of the way, here is what you need to do:

- decide on a name for your function; let's call it `foo`
- declare the function as external with an appropriate type signature in the C source or header files you want to use it from

  ```
  extern int foo(int, int);
  ```
- referring to the ABI document, find the symbol corresponding to your function's identifier; for x86_64-osx, you need to prepend an underscore to the identifier to get the symbol (i.e. `_foo`)
- program your function in an assembly file using your favourite assembler.  Make sure to generate an object file of the correct type.  For x86_64-osx, the correct type is `macho64`, so you should assemble like this:

  ```
  nasm -f macho64 foo.asm
  ```
- make sure to obey the calling convention.  Refer to [this article](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) for a short introduction or read the ABI document linked above.  You should really read it.
- mark the symbol as global using a `global` directive
- finally, include the object file generated by `nasm` into the link

Here's a summary of what you did wrong:

- you didn't use the correct symbol name as you forgot to decorate it with a leading underscore
- you didn't follow the calling convention correctly
- you generated an object file of incorrect type (`elf64` instead of `macho64`)
- you named your section incorrectly (refer to the nasm documention for what section names it accepts for macho64)
- you made some programming mistakes others pointed out that prevented your function from working anyway

Comment: This an awesome and knowledge-expanding answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by the error message, the compiler expects to find the function with a leading underscore in the name, i.e., you need to also export `_add_imm` from your NASM code. I find it convenient to use a macro for this.

The name will solve the compiler error, but your assembly code is also wrong, e.g., you are overwriting `rsp` with `rbp` when it should be the opposite, i.e., `mov rbp, rsp`. (Intel and AT&T syntax have the order of operands reversed, maybe this is the source of confusion.)

It is also extremely likely that your calling convention is wrong for C on an 64-bit x86 platform, i.e., the arguments should be in registers and not on the stack.

```
section .text

%macro export_function 1
global %1, _%1
_%1:
%endmacro

export_function add_imm
add_imm:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rax, rdi  ; (calling convention assumed, check yours)
    add rax, rsi
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

(The `rsp` and `rbp` juggling is obviously not needed for this function to work, but corrected here since they were included in the original.)

Comment: You are right about the rbp, rsp thing. Thank you! Unfortunately, the first part of your answer is not correct, since I made the mistake and used -f elf64 in macOS

Comment: @Niclas Which part is incorrect? I just tried this on macOS, just changing `-f elf64` to `-f macho64` and it works just fine. And if I use your original code, it doesn't work with `-f macho64` because it is missing the underscore and using an incorrect calling convention, just like I stated in my answer. Anyway, I have some macOS x86-64 assembly experiments here: https://github.com/arkku/asm-x64-macos/

Comment: ah ok, I have misunderstood you. I am sorry, you are 100% correct!